# Export from layer to Excel in QGIS with alias fields

Tags: qgis, export, excel

How can I export a layer to Excel format in QGIS environment and have alias of the fields in the header of the Excel file instead of the original field names?

Comment: Question edited by the community. A PyQGIS solution is still acceptable.

Comment: Use 'Export to spreadsheet' algorithm from the Processing Toolbox and tick the checkbox to 'Use field aliases as column headings' ??

Comment: @BenW I think this should be the answer.

Comment: So it worked ok with Arabic & Farsi aliases? If so, great- I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @BenW yes. no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the processing algorithm 'Export to spreadsheet' from the Processing Toolbox and tick the checkbox to 'Use field aliases as column headings'.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could use the "refactor fields" algorithm from the processing toolbox to create fields with the alias as name and fill them using the original field name as source. This lets you manually define the field names for the exported dataset.

You can then export this algorithm as script and use python to generate the configuration for the fields.

## Save features as

Since QGIS 3.26 it's possible with the "save features as" functionality, right click on a vector layer.

[image]

Comment: Faced an issue when working with `Refactor Fields`. Encoding problem with `Name`. Currently the aliases are Arabic or Farsi which it chooses the original name in this case.

Comment: BTW this creates a new Layer which makes the whole process complicated.

Comment: The functionality was introduced in the standard vector layer export dialog since QGIS 3.26.0.